# Generator send() function skip some element

Tags: python, generator

it seems that the generator function `infinite_palindromes` skips one palindrome 101. First `is_palindrome` is to check if a positive integer is palindrome or not. Then the generator function `infinite_palindromes` is defined to produce a generator object `pal_gen`. Afterwards, there is a `for` loop to iterate through the generator object `pal_gen` until the digits of the palindrome number are three. The whole code is as follows:

```
def is_palindrome(num):
    if num // 10 == 0:
        return False
    temp = num
    reversed_num = 0

    while temp != 0:
        reversed_num = (reversed_num * 10) + (temp % 10)
        temp = temp // 10
    if num == reversed_num:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def infinite_palindromes():
    num = 0
    while True:
        if is_palindrome(num):
            print(is_palindrome(num))
            i = (yield num)
            print("after yield {0}".format(i))
            if i is not None:
                num = i
                print("before increment {0}".format(num))
        num += 1
        print("after increment {0}".format(num))

pal_gen = infinite_palindromes()

for i in pal_gen:
    print("--{0}".format(i))
    digits = len(str(i))
    if digits == 3:
        pal_gen.close()
    pal_gen.send(10**digits)
```

The result is as follows:

```
after increment 1
after increment 2
after increment 3
after increment 4
after increment 5
after increment 6
after increment 7
after increment 8
after increment 9
after increment 10
after increment 11
True
--11
after yield 100
before increment 100
after increment 101
True
after yield None
after increment 102
after increment 103
after increment 104
after increment 105
after increment 106
after increment 107
after increment 108
after increment 109
after increment 110
after increment 111
True
--111
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_generator_send.py", line 35, in <module>
    pal_gen.send(10**digits)
StopIteration
```

I don't understand why the palindrome 101 is not printed in the `for` loop. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The behavior of ```pal_gen``` is different when replacing ```is_palindrome(num)``` by this statement ```return str(num) == str(num)[::-1]```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a re-work of your code that will generate palindromic integers of a minimum 2 and maximum 3 digits:

```
def ispalindrome(x):
    assert x >= 0
    if x < 11:
        return False
    n = 0
    x_ = x
    while x > 0:
        n *= 10
        n += x % 10
        x //= 10
    return n == x_

def genpalindrome():
    x = 11
    while True:
        if ispalindrome(x):
            yield x
        x += 1

for p in genpalindrome():
    if p >= 1_000:
        break
    print(p)
```